# Java Switch hitting two cases

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm trying to handle combinatoric user input with switch cases to process, and it seemed to be going well until the final switch

```
    System.out.println("\t output switch =  " + state.get(2));
    switch(state.get(2)){
        //Case MCNP
        case 0:
        {
            abundances = verifyAndNorm(abundances, new MCNPVerifier(MCNP));
            out = toMCNP(mat, abundances);
            System.out.println("\t MCNP");
        }

        //Case SCALE
        case 1:
        {
            abundances = verifyAndNorm(abundances, new SCALEVerifier(SCALE));
            out = toSCALE(mat, abundances, weightFracFlag);
            System.out.println("\t SCALE");
        }
    }
```

Prints out

```
 output switch =  0
 MCNP
 SCALE
```

And the result is that out = toScale(...), and since it is printing both MCNP and SCALE, it must be hitting both cases, but it's only true for one...

What am I missing here?

Comment: Here happens the so-called `fall-through`

Comment: At this point in my life cycle, I'd hope not to be considered a beginner, good to be humbled but still unfun.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

add break statements to each case

```
System.out.println("\t output switch =  " + state.get(2));
switch(state.get(2)){
    //Case MCNP
    case 0:
    {
        abundances = verifyAndNorm(abundances, new MCNPVerifier(MCNP));
        out = toMCNP(mat, abundances);
        System.out.println("\t MCNP");
        break;
    }

    //Case SCALE
    case 1:
    {
        abundances = verifyAndNorm(abundances, new SCALEVerifier(SCALE));
        out = toSCALE(mat, abundances, weightFracFlag);
        System.out.println("\t SCALE");
        break;
    }
    default:
}
```

Comment: Don't you want a second `break` on case 2?

Comment: Like there is a race on the answer :p

Comment: I was 16 seconds late... Deleting my duplicate post :( :p

Comment: I think we have all made this mistake many times :)

Comment: Switch case looks harmless but explicit requirement of makes it error prone, it is better to use if-else for readability/maintainability for sake

Comment: If 0 and 1 are the only possible return values of state.get(), then using if-else is probably better than using a switch construct. But if there are many more possible value, the switch construct is best. Also the OP should consider having state.get() return an enum, which would make the switch construct more readable:

Comment: Literally realized this as I left for a meeting.

And there are baseline of 3 cases possible, more with anticipated scope creep.  Enuming is probably a good idea, though I hadn't considered it as I could have just passed a string of IDs from the calling buttons and that seemed to heavy handed on locking in the UI naming conventions that would be prone to explosion later, but it's a project in the works.